# Leaflet drawing tiles disjointly

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am instantiating a leaflet map, but the tiles are basically being scattered all over the page - while the map is within a div, most of the tiles are not respecting that boundary:

```
<div class="widget-content listing-search-map-widget-content">
    <div class="ih-map" 
         id="Map_5333811_16"
         style="height:450px;"
         data-centerpoint="38.573955 -121.442478" 
         data-mousewheel="true" 
         data-maptype="TERRAIN"
         data-zoom="8"
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript comes down to:

```
mapOptions = {
               attributionControl: true,
               center: {
                   lat: 38.573955
                   lng: -121.442478
               },
               centerpoint: "38.573955,-121.442478", 
               layers: {},
               maptype: "Terrain", 
               scrollWheelZoom: false, 
               zoom: 8
            }

var map = L.map( "Map_5333811_16", mapOptions );
```

What would cause the tiles to plot all over the place?a couple of tiles are within the bounds of the div, but not the rest of them. You can see a screenshot of what happens here:

[image: screenshot of jumbled tiles]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This sounds like a symptom of missing Leaflet CSS file, or incorrect version of that file.

Comment: arg... missed a line deep in a smarty template. Thanks for the pointer, that fixed it all up.

Comment: I am using Polymer 2 with leaflet and don't seem to find any CSS issue. Here is my post in SO: stackoverflow.com/questions/53872322/…. Hope you can help.

Comment: what file was missing?

Answer (score 9):

As has been pointed out, this is solved by importing the CSS files.

Classically, you include the link to your CSS stylesheet in the head section of your document:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```

Or, in my case, stumbling across this problem while adapting [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)'s [Webpack template](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/structure.html), by adding

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

into the `main.js` file.

---

The key lines of CSS appear to be these:

```
.leaflet-layer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

so knowing that you can insert them at whatever point in your project suits your style.

Comment: Note: importing a CSS file in JS is specific to your build engine (typically webpack). In this very case, OP does not seem to use any.

Comment: Fair point, but the OP's problem was solved three and a half years ago. Thought it worth sharing the specific solution I needed!

Answer (score 2):

add these to your index.html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
          integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
          crossorigin=""></script>
```