# Leaflet flipping tiles in electron

Tags: javascript, leaflet, electron, openstreetmap

Hey im new to electron but i want to use Leaflet inside it to some magic mapping stuff.

I created an basic electron application with the index.js according to the basic example.
I added also an basic index.hetml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>Page Title</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

<script>
    require('./renderer')
</script>

</html>
```

And the Leaflet stuff inside the renderer.js

```
window.L = require('leaflet')

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.0420175, 13.7358889], 12)

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
```

When I'm running the app the window is opening and also some MapTiles are displayed.
But they they are not all loaded and they get messed up when im reseizing the window:

[image: Window before reseizing]

and

[image: Window after reseizing]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet drawing tiles disjointly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835758/leaflet-drawing-tiles-disjointly)

Comment: when I'm adding the <link rel="stylesheet" , href="./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"> in my header the map is not displaying anymore

Comment: Grey "tiles don't load" map, or "I forgot to set the height of my map container" invisible map?

Comment: did it before with 100 % -.-
is it possible to give th container a varying width and heigth?

Comment: 100% of *what*?

Comment: of the surroundig element.
I added display flex to the body and flex: 1 to the map container now its working as desired.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem.
I think the best solution is to

```
bower install leaflet
```

and than use this in the head of your .html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
<style>
  body { margin:0; padding:0;  }
  #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0;  }
</style>
```