# why leaflet map doesn't render on react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I included leaflet map with `js` implementation instead of `jsx` implementation but I have a problem as it overflows its scope.

this is how I imported leaflet:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
```

and implemented:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // create map
    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [49.8419, 24.0315],
      zoom: 16,
      layers: [
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }),
      ]
    });
  }
```

and usage:

```
<div id={"map"} >
```

and this is what i got
[image]

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38836996/2626313

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet drawing tiles disjointly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835758/leaflet-drawing-tiles-disjointly)

Comment: adding leaflet css file fixed the problem, thanks @xmojmr

Answer (score 4):

You have not added the leaflet css file in your `index.html`.

For leaflet version `1.3.4`, add the following to index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```

In your map component css file, override the `leaflet-container` class with desired height and width.

```
.leaflet-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Once you have added that, use `Map` and `TileLayer` Components of `react-leaflet` to render map.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 13
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can find working code here. https://codesandbox.io/s/2wnv7o1mlr

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you're missing the css file.

incidentally this is not how you should be using `react-leaflet`.
componentDidMount is not the place for doing what you're doing. Put that in the render like

```
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'; 
<Map>
      <TileLayer url="'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'" />
</Map>
```