# With different versions of leaflet api and css map is broken

Tags: vuejs2, leaflet

In my vue/cli 4/vuex / bootstrap-vue app I added leaflet and got broken layout.
Asking I have got a link to this 
[Leaflet drawing tiles disjointly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835758/leaflet-drawing-tiles-disjointly)
branch, saying that I did not include css in my file.
On the link I found :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```

Looks like that is the only css on this page.
   So I opened the link and copied all css into my .vue file
   in block

```
   <style lang="scss" scoped>
      ...
    </style>
```

Also I uploaded all images from these links into project/public/images
and edited all all images path in the definitions.
But map was not looked properly and looks like:

[image]

In my code I init map with :

```
        var pointsMap = L.map('mapid', {zoomControl: false}).setView([51.505, -0.09], 7);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
            maxZoom: 5,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1
        }).addTo(pointsMap);
```

Can the issue be with different versions of leaflet api and css ?

How better to deal it?

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious inquiry here is: What version of Leaflet are you using?

Comment: In /package.json I have : "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
and in JS code I have : tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94

I got css definitions from https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css
I suppose it is similar 1.6 in package.json ?

Comment: Sounds like you're using the same versions for the JS and CSS files (1.6.0 vs 1.6.0), so your question as written in its title makes no sense. I would advise to rephrase and to make a [minimal repeoducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What if you remove the `scoped` attribute of your `<style>` tag?

Comment: if to remove the scoped attribute then I have empty map div