# Issue with Leaflet js Map not fitting inside a div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

So I'm trying to add a leaflet js map inside a placeholder div, but I'm getting the following:

[image]

the **placeholder div** is the **centre square** but apparently the **map is pouring out** of the div as shown above. Why is this happening?

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}

.map_panel {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>mapform</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "outer">
        <div class = "map_panel">
            <div id = "embed_map">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <script>
        //Creating map options
        var mapOptions = {
            center: [35.7101, 139.8107],
            zoom: 15
        }

        //Creating a map object
        var map = new L.map('embed_map', mapOptions);
        L.marker(mapOptions.center).addTo(map);
        //Creating a Layer object
        var layer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

        //Adding layer to the map
        map.addLayer(layer);
    </script>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leaflet drawing tiles disjointly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835758/leaflet-drawing-tiles-disjointly)

Answer (score 0):

Next time please look that your code is working, because what you have posted has not the same result as in the image and you have not defined the `map` and the `outer` css style but I think this is the `output2` style.

I tested the code and it is working for me, the map is not overlapping. BUT if you have a situation that it is overlapping, then you can add `overflow: hidden;`  to hide all what is out of the box.

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/duag5qfc/

Also it looks like you have not added the [Leaflet css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css) styles

Comment: yes i just realized the naming of "outer" and "output2". edited that. Can you tell me why its overflowing?

Comment: @Astrox add the leaflet css style then it works, also you need to define a `wdith` and `height`for `#embed_map`